# Working on UNIX/Linux for C programming on Windows 8.1

Tags: windows

Do I need to download any UNIX / Linux software for starting C programming on
Windows 8.1?

Comment: Probably the best way forward for you is to download a Linux distribution and install it next (or preferably over) Windows 8 and do your C programming. Most distributions come with C compilers installed unless you do a real minimal installation. This is not really C programming on Windows 8, if that is really necessary install Linux in a virtual machine and run the C compiler under Linux. And since Linux is under Win 8.1 you will run the C compiler under Windows 8.1. Requirement met and sanity preserved.

Answer (score 2):

No, to program in C on Windows you can use an IDE such as [Code::Blocks](http://www.codeblocks.org/) or [Visual Studio](https://www.visualstudio.com/); if you're just looking for a C compiler, check out [mingw-w64](http://mingw-w64.org/doku.php).

If you're trying to develop in C on a Unix/Linux system and target Windows, you can find an appropriate cross-compiler on [mingw-w64](http://mingw-w64.org/doku.php) (and probably in your Linux distribution if you're running Linux).